# Elasticsearch wildcard case-sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

How to make wildcard case-insensitive?

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Answer (score 15):

Since version 7.10 the `wildcard` query supports special parameter `case_insensitive` (boolean).
Example of case-insensitive search:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "my_field": {
        "value": "ki*y",
        "case_insensitive": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great. This did work correctly when I fired a query from Kibana.
Unfortunately, I couldn't see it in their .NET SDK. I used NEST 7.11.1 for .NET, and I couldn't see ths "case_insensitive" option at all. Wierd!

Comment: Just tried this on version 7.13 and it didn't work. I set case_insensitive to false and true but allways get same results.

Answer (score 6):

Wildcards are not_analyzed. It depends on what analyzers you've provided for the field you're searching. But if you're using the default analyzers then a wildcard query will return **case-insensitive** results.

Example: Post two names in a sample index one is "Sid" and other "sid".

```
POST sample/sample
{
  "name" : "sid"
}

POST sample/sample
{
  "name" : "Sid"
}
```

Then perform a wildcard query:

```
GET sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "name": {
        "value": "s*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will return me both the documents:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "sample",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "AWRPM87Wb6oopELrnEKE",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "Sid"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "sample",
        "_type": "sample",
        "_id": "AWRPM9tpb6oopELrnEKF",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "name": "sid"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But if you perform a wildcard query on "S*" it will return nothing. Because the default token filter stores the terms in lowercase and the term "Sid" is stored as "sid" in the inverted index.

Comment: It is recommended to use `wildcard` query with the special `wildcard` field type which doesn't support analyzers and normalizers. That's why by default it won't be case-insensitive unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this is not true, it is case sensitive by default - I am using ES 7.2. 
In you sample the type of the field is "text" not "keyword"

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same option for nodejs client, so came across this question, so posting as an answer might help someone else.

I have to convert the term to lowercase and its worked for me `*${term.toLowerCase()}*`
Here is the complete function

```
searchUsers(term, from, limit) {
    let users = await EsClient.search({
        index: 'users',
        type: 'users',
        body: {
            from,
            size: limit,
            query: {
                bool: {
                    should: [
                        {
                            wildcard: {
                                email: {
                                    value: `*${term.toLowerCase()}*`
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            wildcard: {
                                "name.keyword": {
                                    value: `*${term.toLowerCase()}*`
                                }
                            }
                        }
                      ],
                    must_not: {
                        terms: {_id: blacklist}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This worked for me using elasticsearch 6.2 with the c# nest api